# Unreliable network connection

Tags: wifi, internet

My friend has a cafe (coffeeshop) you could seat maybe 40-50 people in here, so its not that big a place.
He provides every customer with free internet (password protected) that I helped him setup.

**Here is how we do it:**
he purchased a 50mb/50mb connection.
and from our provider (the biggest and most reliable in the country), we were sent a router.
Now that router we had set to tunnelmode, and purchased a strong one.
Jensen Scandinavia Air:Link 7000AC

It was placed in the middle of the room, just under the sealing, which Means the furthest distance to a customer is maybe 20feet.
we set it up for dynamic IP, and I think the ticket renewal is like 6 hours.
It is setup with 2ghz and 5ghz

**Here is the problem:**

it will just randomly drop people. 
right now there are maybe 18 devices connected to that router, now 10 of them will be able to browse and use the internet without expericing any issues, and if they do a speedtest they will see that the speed is good.

Now the remaining 8 devices lose connection every 10th minute or so for 1-2 minutes then get back on.

Its like that if there are 10 people here or if there are 60 people here.

I had the provider monitor the connection and they told me it was completely stabile.

So I have no clue what to check/do
can you help me?

Comment: Purchase decent business grade Wi-Fi equipment. The Jensen device you have was designed to handle maybe 5-10 devices in a typical home.

Comment: really?

I go to cafees I just dont see better equiptment than that.
you sure thats the issue?

Comment: Definitely. Cheaper devices can't handle crowded WiFi fabric very well at all. There are standards to mitigate these issues, and they require a fair amount of processing power - and are typically not included in home WiFi equipment. Also consider that the spectrum you're operating on may be more crowded than you expect if there are other businesses with WiFi around.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M It's worse than that. You can have WiFi, Bluetooth, microwave ovens, and proprietary protocols all compete for the same spectrum.

Comment: Lol almost forgot about all that stuff. And God forbid there's heavy machinery with inductive loads nearby. Those things throw off everything from DC to light.

Comment: Have you looked at logs to see if there are any errors.  Is the DHCP server configured to provide sufficient IP address leases.  Given the 6 hour lease time, it is possible to run out of IP addresses if café is busy.  Have you checked for conflicting networks( as noted by @ SmallLoanOf1M) .  A nearby device on same channel(s) could create issues.